# Visioglobe map and Metaio AR with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, metaio

I want to use these tools with Xamarin

- [Visioglobe 3d maps](http://visioglobe.com/our-solutions/visiodevkit-sdk/)
- [Metaio SDK for Augmented reality](http://metaio.com)

they are working well with native android and iOS apps.

And I would like to know if we can use these tools with Xamarin, Does xamarin support them?

And how to integrate a Xamarin app with them.

Answer (score 0):

[DISCLAIMER] I'm an engineer at Visioglobe.

You've probably moved on already, but I'll reply anyway in case someone else is interested.

To this date, there is no indication, either way, that Visioglobe's VisioMove SDK will work with the Xamarin platform.

If you have already chosen Visioglobe for your application's map, then I would suggest strongly to use the traditional IDE's to reduce any risk of potential conflicts.